# how can i use wsHttpBinding in wcf without using any certificate

Tags: wcf, wshttpbinding

I want to use wsHttpBinding in a wcf service, the wsHttpBinding is required to a certificate for security issues, but i want using wsHttpBinding without security, is this applicable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `Message` security with `Windows` authentication:

```
<security mode="Message">
     <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
</security>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want use wsHttpBinding instead of basicHttpBinding, but maybe [Difference between BasicHttpBinding and WsHttpBinding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36396/Difference-between-BasicHttpBinding-and-WsHttpBind) and [Use wsHttpBinding with Windows Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650619.aspx), can be useful for you.